# How can I acquire a semaphore and release it from another task in FreeRTOS in STM32H?

Tags: stm32, stm, stm32h7, stm32-hal

I have enabled TIM1 and have created 3 tasks where the highest priority task will acquire the semaphore and will sleep for 10 seconds after that the normal priority task will sleep for 10 secnds and release the semaphore, after this the lower priority task will acquire the semaphore and blink the LEDs
But that's not happening only the Higher priority task is acquiring the semaphore waiting for 10 seconds and again it's acquiring the semaphore

what seems to be the problem??

I have attached the snippet of the code here

```
void StartHighTask(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN StartHighTask */
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
      if ( osSemaphoreAcquire(BinSemHandle, osWaitForever)== osOK){
                    char *s1 = " Semaphore Acquired by High Task\n\r";
                    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t*)s1, strlen(s1), 1000);
                    HAL_Delay(10000);


                  }

                  else {
                    char *s3 = " Waiting for the Semaphore \n\r";
                HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t*)s3, strlen(s3), 1000);
                  }


    osDelay(1000);
  }
  /* USER CODE END StartHighTask */
}

/* USER CODE END Header_StartNormalTask */
void StartNormalTask(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 5 */
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
      HAL_Delay(10000);
      osSemaphoreRelease(BinSemHandle);
      char *s2 = " Semaphore released by Normal Task\n\r";
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t*)s2, strlen(s2), 1000);

    osDelay(1000);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 5 */
}

/* USER CODE END Header_StartLowTask */
void StartLowTask(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN StartLowTask */
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
      if ( osSemaphoreAcquire(BinSemHandle, osWaitForever)== osOK){

                    char *s1 = " Semaphore Acquired by low Task\n\r";
                    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t*)s1, strlen(s1), 1000);

                    osDelay(1000);
                    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_14, 1);
                    HAL_Delay(500);
                    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_14, 0);

                    char *s2 = " Semaphore released by low Task\n\r";
                    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t*)s2, strlen(s2), 1000);
                osSemaphoreRelease(BinSemHandle);


                  }

                  else {
                    char *s3 = " Waiting for the Semaphore \n\r";
                HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t*)s3, strlen(s3), 1000);
                  }

    osDelay(1000);
  }
  /* USER CODE END StartLowTask */
}
```

Comment: I think you have to replace busy waiting HAL_Delay() with osDelay().

Comment: Yes I replaced it now I got the output